# Why can't I chat in Mathematics chat room?

Tags: support, chat

I am not able to write anything on mathematics chat room, what could be the problem. 
I need help. thanks.
I have tried many times but been unsuccessful. Is it possible that someone blocked me or something?

before trying to send a message.
[image]

after clicking 'send'[image]

[image]

Comment: The Mathematics room is not restricted in any way. Are you logged in or does the login for chat fail?

Comment: @MadScientist : I can log in , but if i want to enter my comment it doesn't work . my answer gets deleted . and doesn't appear .

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what happens? Either you're not really logged in (login in chat is separate from the main site), or this is some kind of browser bug, I suspect. You can't block individual users from a chat room, mods can only suspend (and you're not suspended)

Comment: Hmm, weird. I'm seeing no message posting attempts from you in the access logs. Are there any errors in the JavaScript console (Menu button -> Tools -> JavaScript console)?

Comment: @balpha : i have posted the screen shot .can u explain me which menu button u mean ?

Comment: This one: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aKXrE.png in the top right

Comment: @balpha : i have posted here .

Comment: That "Failed to load resource" line is very suspicious (it's not coming from the chat), and a Google search for "topictorch netseer com" suggest that you may have picked up malware, possible in a browser add-on. Try to disable all extensions (Menu button -> Tools -> Extensions, then uncheck all "active" checkboxes) and reload the chat page.

Comment: @balpha : thanks now it works